# Dial passcode from bridge conference call using objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.3

I need to dial passcode automatically after dialing conference number from an iPhone app. I tried to make the call and the call gets connected. How can I dial the passcode automatically after the call get connected?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the character 'p' to introduce a 1 second delay. Digits after the first pause will be sent as post-dial digits using DTMF.

So if your conference access number was 1800123456 and the access code was 987654 then you would specify something like.

```
Tel://1800123456pp987654
```

You may need to add more p characters - it can be a bit trial and error.

See [RFC2806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806/)